# For $z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos\alpha$ calculate $z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}$ If $n$ is a positive integer

Tags: complex-numbers

For $z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos\alpha$ calculate   $z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}$ If $n$ is a positive integer

***here's my first attempt***

$z^2-2\cos\alpha+1=0$ so we have $z=\cos\alpha\pm i\sin\alpha= e^{\pm i\alpha}$

but I thought there is a simple approach

What other approach would you suggest?

Comment: This is the proper approach.  If that is the value of $z$, what is $z^n$?

Comment: $z^n=e^{\pm in\alpha}$

Comment: Which yields a final answer of....?

Comment: Aron, here is where I don't find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\small z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos{\alpha}\iff\left(z-\cos{\alpha}\right)^{2}+\sin^{2}{\alpha}=0\iff z=\cos{\alpha}\pm\mathrm{i}\sin{\alpha}\iff z=\mathrm{e}^{\pm\mathrm{i}\alpha}\iff z^{n}=\mathrm{e}^{\pm n\mathrm{i}\alpha} $$

Thus : $$ z^{n}+\frac{1}{z^{n}}=\mathrm{e}^{\pm n\mathrm{i}\alpha}+\mathrm{e}^{\mp n\mathrm{i}\alpha}=2\cos{\left(n\alpha\right)} $$

Comment: CHAMSI,So beautiful solution, thanks